# Graphics Problem on Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB RAM) on Browsers and VLC

Tags: pi-4, vlc, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, firefox

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) that works fine graphically when I remote desktop into it, as soon below
[image]

However, when I open Firefox or Chromium, I get distorted graphics.
[image]

Additionally, when I use my Raspberry Pi to Chromecast a video to my smart TV using VLC, the video occasionally gets slightly distorted until a sufficiently different graphical image updates the screen in the stream (as to update all the pixels).

What might be causing these graphical issues?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on several Pi4's I have deployed with bookworm:

1. Add the xrdp user to the ssl-cert group:
   $ **sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert**
2. Modify the **/etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf** file and change the 'Option DRM
   Device' line to:

**Option "DRMDevice" ""** (that's a space, and two double-quotes).

Comment: This worked very well. It was *Option "DRMDevice" "/dev/dri/renderD128"* and I changed as you said and things worked fine.